# How to get back a URL without performing the redirection gwt?

Tags: gwt

there is someone who can solve my problem??
How to get back a URL without performing the redirection gwt???

Comment: I want to send data to a server (through the URL). I like to get the result???

Comment: I mean, what have you coded? What did you try to get that done?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is asked in an other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993681/how-can-i-get-the-url-that-the-page-is-redirected-from/13994647#13994647), there I just answered it.

[How can I get the URL that the page is redirected from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993681/how-can-i-get-the-url-that-the-page-is-redirected-from/13994647#13994647)