# How can I get the URL that the page is redirected from?

Tags: gwt

I have a login servlet and it will redirect to my GWT page.

I want to make sure the page is redirected from that login servlet. How can I make sure that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a [JSNI Method](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI) like this:

```
public static native String getReferrer() /*-{
  return $doc.referrer;
}-*/;
```

Comment: No need for JSNI: [`Document.get().getReferrer()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Document.html#getReferrer%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Guess you would like to avoide any unauthorized approach? If so I would suggest to use JAAS in your AS. You should deny any access to your gwt page if the user is not successfully authenticated. JAAS is a complex topic though. I could give you some examples if you need them.